Error Updating V2 Cloud Functions in Firebase
I'm trying to update some V2 cloud functions in Firebase but keep encountering an error. Previously, I managed to deploy these functions without any issues. Below is the log from my deployment attempt:
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8561

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/main/documents/demos/test/functions (77.78 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...

Error: Error generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com.

I'm unsure what to do next to resolve this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If the Firebase CLI gives you an error message that's not easy to understand, you should reach out to Firebase support for assistance.

I faced the same issue, logout and login to Firebase CLI worked.
(firebase logout thenfirebase login)
